# Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on ... using `parserOptions.project`: ... However, that TSConfig does not include this file

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, tsconfig, eslintrc

I got this error on Eslint Typescript in VSCode.
[image]

I have installed

- [Prettier Eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint)
- [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- nodejs v18.17.0 using NVM

My current OS is `Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon`.

I have followed several answers on stack overflow such as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413483/eslint-cypress-parsing-error-eslint-was-configured-to-run-on-tsconfigrootd) question, but have no luck.

this is my `parserOptions.project` in `eslintrc`:

```json
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"],
        "sourceType": "module",
        "tsconfigRootDir": "."
    },
```

and this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "./**/*.ts",
    "**/__tests__/*",
    "**/*.test*",
    "**/*.spec*",
    ".eslintrc"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [".eslintrc"],
}
```

`tsconfig.base.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES5",
      "ES6",
      "ESNext",
      "ES2022",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "newLine": "LF",
    "noEmit": false,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "pretty": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "tests",
    "**/__tests__/*",
    "**/*.test*",
    "**/*.spec*",
    "**/*deprecate*",
    "**/*ignored*"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.path.json",
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  }
}
```

and `tsconfig.path.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "@common/*": [
        "src/core/common/helpers/*"
      ],
      "@config/*": [
        "src/config/*"
      ],
      "@core/*": [
        "src/core/*"
      ],
      "@dependency/*": [
        "src/dependency/*"
      ],
      "@infra/*": [
        "src/infra/*"
      ],
      "@rootPath/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@ui/*": [
        "src/ui/*"
      ]
    },
    "rootDir": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./@types",
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

and in `package.json` i installed

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.59.5",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59",
  "typescript": "~4.9.5
}
```

What confuses me is:

- This configuration works out of the box in windows. what's wrong?
- it works if it uses absolute path such as `"project": "/home/ijash/company/apps/appName/tsconfig.json"`